# determine if string contains only numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, friendly-id

I'm using [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) for my routes in my rails app.

I want to ensure that a page cannot be visited by the numeric id.

A page is accessible like this - www.myurl.com/myfriendlyidstub

The page should not be accessible like this -  www.myurl.com/12345 (12345 is the id of myfriendlyidstub)

I can't see a way to do this in friendly_id's docs.

So I'm considering adding a method in my controller to check whether the param is numeric

```
def edit
    if params[:id].is_numeric? #I need to know how to write this method
        not_found #not_found redirects to a 404
    end 
    #rest of the edit action
end
```

Two questions -

How do I write the 'is_numeric' method?

Is this a good way of doing things? Can you see any pitfalls?

Comment: you may want to check out [this link](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=19081). i don't see a problem with the approach as such, although i *think* you can do regex in the routes themselves if you like.

Comment: On another note, whitelisting would be a better approach than blacklisting (specify what is valid input, rather than specifying invalid input)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a `before_filter` before sticking it in every method.

You may also configure a routing [segment constraint](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to have user names as a permalink right after the root '/'...

```
config/route.rb
...
match '/:id' => 'controller#show'
...
```

After that I believe if you setup Friendly It correctly it should display as a name instead of an id.

btw thanks for finding friendly_id, I was about to start looking for something like that for my project.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: that's how I set it up originally - but my issue was that I wanted to obscure the actual Ids. Which I did as per the accepted answer. Friendly_id works great though. The owner of the repo on git hub is very helpful too.